# Is there a way to get multiple lines of input at once without tapping Ctrl+Z?

Tags: python, input, multiline

i found two way to get multi-line input,

```
import sys

msg = sys.stdin.readlines()
msg2 = sys.stdin.read()
```

but both way need to stop with additional `Ctrl+Z` to end input

Is there a way to get multiple lines of input at once, without tapping additional `Ctrl+Z`?

for Copy and Paste some multiple lines of texts to a input(a string), so input will over with one `Enter`
or better end with just `Ctrl+V`

Comment: How do you determine if the input is over? Can you just call `input()` in a loop for a fixed number of lines, or until you find an empty line?

Comment: Sorry for lack of information, Edited

Comment: Multiple `input()` in a `while` or `for` loop seems to work fine with copy-pasting multiple lines.

Comment: You can't do that with the stdin. Use a GUI framework such as tkinter, PySide6, etc.

Comment: The only problem is, when reading input, typing "enter" is the same as a line-end, so you have to have some other end-of-input condition, like e.g. an empty line. But that won't work if the input contains blank lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter

r = tkinter.Tk()
r.withdraw()

def paste():
    a=input()
    if a=='':
        global text
        text = r.clipboard_get()
```

what i found is this is good i guess, thanks for comments